# How to calculate precision and recall after each epoch in keras?

Tags: keras

I need to calculate precision and recall after each epoch in keras. I found this article:https://medium.com/@thongonary/how-to-compute-f1-score-for-each-epoch-in-keras-a1acd17715a2
in this code:

```
self.model.predict(self.model.validation_data[0])
```

it means the instance of `Model` has a variable named `validation_data`, but I cannot find the definition of `validation_data` in `Model` in keras/models.py file. Where can I find it?

Comment: I had the same issue, I think there is no `self.model.validation_data` if you're using a generator. I ended up passing my validation data generator to a callback and computing scores in `on_epoch_end`. Though I'm not computing scores for the same validation data as keras as I'm sampling a new epoch from the validation generator...

Comment: I find the source code of Callback. There is a variable named `validation_data`

Answer (score 0):

In Keras 1.2.2 Model class is defined on engine/training.py and its validation_data is defined there as well.

In Keras 2, validation_data is a variable of callback and not of Model.